# Swing components won't display some characters correctly in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, fonts, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm using netbeans and can't get to write SOME UTF-8 symbols in `JLabel` components, for example ȵ and ʮ. The weird thing is that both are printed in console normally while they are shown as 口 in labels.

I don't think it's a font problem because they can display without any problem in eclipse. Note they are using exactly the same font, Tahoma.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: *"I don't think it's a font problem because they can display without any problem in eclipse."* What font is Eclipse using? What font is NetBeans using? This is basic debugging, and you should do some of it before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: exactly the same font, Tahoma. I spent more than a hour trying to solve it but I couldn't.

Comment: *"exactly the same font, Tahoma."* Good on you for confirming. *"I spent more than a hour trying to solve it but I couldn't."* Wow. You say that is if an hour is a long time. Note that if you'd mentioned the fonts in the initial post we would not have had to spend 13 hours tacking it down. More information, rather than less, is better in an SO question.

Comment: BTW - can you tell me the Unicode numbers of those (at least) 2 characters? Better still, could you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem using those characters?